# Selenium 2.51 WebDriver C# won't open Firefox on Windows 7 X64

Tags: c#, firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am able to get Firefox to load on Selenium v2.0.50727 to open Firefox using C# .net3.5

but **NOT** able to get **Firefox** to load on **Selenium 2.5.1**, it just hangs (in both **C#** .net3.5/net.4).  I see nothing in the event log.

```
My setup:
Windows 7 x64 OS
Firefox 3.6.20
Tried both .net40 and .net35 in Selenium 2.5.1 but no luck
used platform x86 with platform target any cpu for .net40
used platform  x86 with platform target x86 for .net35
Note: I was able to get Internet Explorer to work.
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this? or a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just posted a question on xpath and noticed your post since I'm using a near identical setup.  The key different being I'm running FF6.0 - but otherwise im running the same OS/.net and selenium versions.  And of course, easy for me to say but it does work on my machine!

Two thoughts came to mind.  I picked up Selenium using the VS2010 NuGet package manager so references were automatically added.  So Ionic.zip v2.0.50727, Newtonson.json v4.0.30319 references were added in addition - I'm sure if these were not present your project wouldn't compile but a thought...

Also http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver it mentions that Selenium looks in a predefined location for the FF exe... so if your installation was different could this perhaps cause a problem (I'm not immediately sure how you change this..) - I would have thought an exception of some sort rather than a 'hang' would be raised but just a thought!

Comment: Thanks for the tips.. I ended up upgrading to FF 6 but still it would not load. I had to uninstall and delete the FF folder and do completely fresh install before Selenium 2.51 WebDriver C# would work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks in the folder C:/Program Files/   If  you just move your entire installation of firefox to program files it will work.

I had the issue on windows 7 with firefox 7 and just cut and paste the whole directory into Program Files and it's working fine.